# Expected a value of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<Color>>', but got one of type 'MappedListIterable<Color, DropdownMenuItem<Color>>'

Tags: flutter, dart

i am tryin to change themeColor from dropdownmenu but getting this error : "Expected a value of type 'List>', but got one of type
'MappedListIterable>'

```
Color  selected ;

MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: selected),
      home: Scaffold();

 List myColor = [
    Colors.amber,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.green,
    Colors.black,
  ];

 DropdownButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
              value: selected,
              onChanged: (value){
                setState(() {
                  selected = value;
                });
              },
              items: myColor.map((value)=>DropdownMenuItem(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value.toString()),
              ))
            ),
```

Answer (score 3):

DropdownButton requires explicit types to correctly match against its items. You're also not turning the iterable returned by `map` back into a list:

```dart
// Before, it's type was List<dynamic>
List<Color> myColor = [ // Add <Color>
  Colors.amber,
  Colors.blue,
  Colors.green,
  Colors.black,
];
```

and

```dart
items: myColor.map(
  (value) => DropdownMenuItem(
    value: value,
    child: Text(value.toString()),
  ),
).toList(), // Add toList()
```

See the [DropdownButton docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) for more details.

Comment: the toList() flattens the output of map